# How to compute a previous balance in sql 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want a code in sql 2008 that will add the previous balance of the table below. Like

```
Balance= + Debit
Balance= -Credit



AccountReceivable
+----+------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+--------+---------+-----+
| ID |  AR_Date   |  Ref_No  | Acc_Code | Acc_Name | Details | Debit | Credit |Balance |     |
+----+------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+--------+---------+-----+
|  1 | 2013-04-10 |          |      101 | A/R      |  Kofi  | 500   | |   0   |      |
|  2 | 2013-04-10 |          |      101 | A/R      |  AMA   |0      | |   250 |      |
|  3 | 2013-04-11 | CH552778 |      101 | A/R      |  Boss  | 0     | |   50  |      |
+----+------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+--------+---------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE in combination with ROW_NUMBER().  After this you can then query the CTE and join on the current row number with the previous.

e.g.

```
;
WITH CTE as (
SELECT
    ac.*,
         RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
FROM
    AccountsReceivable ac

)

SELECT
cur.Balance + prev.Balance AS NewBalance
FROM
CTE cur 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE prev ON cur.RN = prev.RN + 1
```